# How to hide form content from add product forms

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules

I am working on Add Product section customization. Based on role I want to hide Some Fields from Price Tab form content and want to show other Fields instead of that. 
Where are the files to hide fields.
The problem is mentioned in Image. Please go through it for concept clarification.
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-fields-permission.html

This extension provide Product field read only  but you need to  change the code from readonly property  to display none property .